# VBA Rest API Call with API Key Authentication

Tags: vba, rest

I just received my information for a new REST API I need to start collecting data on.

I got a URL, an API Key (token), direction that "the Key for the API Key" is "apikey", and a Username.

I downloaded Postman and was able to do a successful call. To do that, I went to the Authorization tab and entered "apikey" as the key and the provided the API Key (token) as the value. I do not use the provided Username in Postman.

I have a preexisting automation structure written mostly in VBA, so I would prefer to just do the API call from there over incorporating Postman.

Here is the most recent code sample that I am trying to get to do this:

```
Public Sub GetResults()
    Dim data As String, json As Object '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "[Provided URL]"

Set hReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + _
            EncodeBase64("[Username]" + ":" + "[Token]")
        .send
    End With

    Dim response As String
    response = hReq.responseText
    
    MsgBox response

End Sub

Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String

  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  EncodeBase64 = Application.Clean(objNode.text)

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

I have plugged in both the provided username and "apikey" as the "[username]" and I am getting an "API key is missing" error back that tells me the sub is functioning, it is reaching the target, it is receiving a response, but guessing my ".setRequestHeader "Authorization"" statement is not correct.

Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong?

Additionally, I started out with this sub:

```
Sub GetResultData()

Dim hReq As Object, json As Dictionary
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheet1

Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "[Provided URL]"
Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer [Username]:[Token]"
        .send
    End With

Dim response As String
    response = hReq.responseText
    
    MsgBox response

End Sub
```

Got the same results with the same troubleshooting. Saw something suggesting EncodeBase64 is required in VBA, but not sure if that is true or not.

Summary: I have a Username, an "authentication key", and an actual token value. Postman works without using the Username. I can't get past an "API key is missing" when trying to use VBA, and my guess is that I am confused about what "Username:Token" means in the context of ".setRequestHeader "Authorization""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

```
Sub GetResultData()

Dim hReq As Object, json As Dictionary
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheet1

Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = "[Provided URL]"
Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "apikey", "[Token]"
        .send
    End With

Dim response As String
    response = hReq.responseText
    
    MsgBox response

End Sub
```

Answer was to change

```
".setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer [Username]:[Token]""
```

to

```
".setRequestHeader "apikey", "[Token]""
```